# Prevent unauthenticated users to access my Angular 4 app (set it as default)

Tags: angular, firebase

Does anybody have an idea how to prevent unauthenticated users to access my Angular 4 app (set it as default) and allow them to access just a few sites? I know how to do it in the other way - by using [isAuthenticated] tag - but the reverse way still is a great obstacle for me.

Comment: you can use [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

Comment: please check this doc: https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules